# Combinatorial Cross-Validation Embargo and Purged

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn

There is a library on GitHub called [timeseriescv](https://github.com/sam31415/timeseriescv/blob/master/timeseriescv/cross_validation.py) which implements Combinatorial CV. I am trying to use it in conjunction with GridSearchCV. However, unlike normal sklearn cross validators which have a function called "get_n_splits" which returns the number of splits, this package does not have this function. The docstring states: "The samples are decomposed into `n_splits` folds containing equal numbers of samples, without shuffling. In each cross validation round, `n_test_splits` folds are used as the test set, while the other folds are used as the training set. There are as many rounds as `n_test_splits` folds among the `n_splits` folds." So if I was to implement a function called `get_n_splits`, how would I approach this if I have `n_splits` and `n_test_splits`? Here is a snippet of code:

```
from timeseriescv.cross_validation import CombPurgedKFoldCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

cv = CombPurgedKFoldCV(n_splits=5, n_test_splits=2)
cv.X = X
cv.y = y
cv.pred_times = train.Pred_Date
cv.eval_times = train.Eval_Date

print(cv.n_splits, cv.n_test_splits)

# for i, (train_indexes, test_indexes) in enumerate(cv.split(X=X, y=y, pred_times=train.Pred_Date, eval_times=train.Eval_Date)):

param_grid = {'C': [0.1, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.5],
              "tol": [1e3, 1e4],
              "max_iter": [500, 1000]}

model = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True, class_weight="balanced")
gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=cv, verbose=0) # [(train_indexes, test_indexes)]
gs.fit(X, y)
```

Here is the error:

n_splits = cv_orig.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)

AttributeError: 'CombPurgedKFoldCV' object has no attribute 'get_n_splits'